# Click button, turn image and show another div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a screen like this:
[image]

So what I am trying to do is when the CLICK button is clicked, return the image on the right and show the result box (which is div).
[image]

So the section is like this:

```
<section class="weight__calculations">
        <div class="container calculations__content">
          <div class="row contents">
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-12 col-sm-12"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
              <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                <div class="calorie__button__area">
                  <button
                    type="submit"
                    class="button-secondary button__calculate"
                  >
                    HESAPLA
                  </button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
              <img
                  src="./assets/img/calculate.png"
                  alt="Weight Calculation Image"
                />
            </div>
            
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content__result">
              <div class="result__box">
                <div class="title">RESULT</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
```

And I hided calculate__content__result in css:

```
.calculate__content__result {
display:none;
}
```

But I dont know how to show it again and display none picture with the return effect.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this out it may help in your needs... Same time you toggle the class name of image too.

css

```
 .calculate__content__result_show{
       display : block ;
    }
```

jquery

```
$(document).on('click','.click',function(){

  $('.calculate__content__result').toggleClass('calculate__content__result_show');

});
```

javascript

```
var clickBtn = document.querySelector('.click');
var result = document.querySelector('.calculate__content__result');

clickBtn.addEventListerner('click',function(){

   result.classList.toggle('calculate__content__result_show');
   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an ID in the element you want to hide/show

```
<div id="imageDiv" class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 calculate__content">
```

and add functions to hide/show with javascript at the the begining of the html

```
<script>
  function showImage(){
    document.getElementById("imageDiv").style.display = "block";
  }
  function hideImage(){
    document.getElementById("imageDiv").style.display = "none";
  }
</script>
```

Call the functions when needed, for example:

```
<button onclick="showImage()" class="button-secondary button__calculate">
  Click
</button>
```